# Limpiar Inputs y TextArea de un formulario en un Modal de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, bootstrap, modal

El código de la tabla con los botones es el siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Fecha</th>
         <th>Título</th>
         <th>Estado</th>
         <th>Comentarios</th>
         <th>
            Acciones&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" id="btn-noticia" onclick="limpiarFormulario();">Crear noticia</button>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($noticias); $i++) {
            $noticia_actual = $noticias[$i][0];
            $comentarios_noticia_actual = $noticias[$i][1];
            ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerFecha(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerTitulo(); ?>a</td>
         <td><?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerEstado(); ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $comentarios_noticia_actual; ?></td>
         <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Editar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Borrar</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
         }
         ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

El código del modal que contiene los Inputs y el TextArea es:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-10">
                <label><strong>Titulo:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Título de la noticia" value="<?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerTitulo(); ?>"/><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-2">
                <label><strong>Publicar:</strong></label><br/>
                <label class="switch">
            <input id="estado" type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
            </div>
            <label><strong>Texto:</strong></label>
                <textarea cols="12" id="texto" name="texto" class="form-control"><?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerTexto(); ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Por ultimo el código JavaScript que tengo hecho:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-noticia").on("click",function() {
        $('#titulo').val('');
        $('#estado').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
        $('#texto').val('');
    });
    </script>
```

La problemática es que cuando limpio los campos al darle en el botón CREAR NOTICIA, y vuelvo a dar click en el botón editar debería mostrarme nuevamente los campos con la información obtenida por medio de PHP, pero los campos se muestran vacíos.

Agradezco cualquier contribución para dar solución a este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa tu código html, olvidaste declarar el atributo ID en el checkbox de publicar:

```
  <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label><strong>Publicar:</strong></label><br/>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" id="estado">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
  </div>
```

Al igual que en txtarea:

```
    <label><strong>Texto:</strong></label>
            <textarea cols="12" name="texto" id="texto" class="form-control"><></textarea>
```

Hice algunos cambios en tu codigo javascript:

```
$("#btn-noticia").on("click",function() {
    $('#titulo').val('');
    $('#estado').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
    $('#texto').val('');
});
```

Si la respuesta te ayuda, recuerda marcarla como correcta. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Gracias por la observación del ID. Cuando abro el modal con información recuperada y mostrada para editarla por primera vez todos los datos se ven, pero cuando quiero abrir el modal con el botón noticia solo me borrar el contenido del titulo. Y cuando vuelvo a abrir el modal con la información recuperada no me muestra el titulo. D:

Comment: Agregaste los cambios que sugeri a tu código javascript? Si tienes problemas puedes actualizar la descripción de tu pregunta con el nuevo código que tienes ahora.

Comment: Listo ya aplique las correcciones que me brindaste y actualice la pregunta. Por favor, revisala nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

La solución a la problemática actual es:

```
$("#btn-editar").on("click",function() {
$('#titulo').val('<?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerTitulo(); ?>');
$('textarea').val('<?php echo $noticia_actual -> obtenerTexto(); ?>');
});
```

Con eso recupero los datos nuevamente al entrar al modal con el botón editar.